# How do I assert that an HTTP exception was raised?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests, pytest

I'm making an HTTP request using the [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. If the request fails, an exception is raised. For example (truncated and simplified):

`main.py`

```py
from requests import get


def make_request():
    r = get("https://httpbin.org/get")
    r.raise_for_status()
```

I've written a test using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) that mocks the request.

`test_main.py`

```py
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import patch

import pytest
from requests import HTTPError

from main import make_request


@patch("main.get")
def test_main_exception(mock_get):
    exception = HTTPError(mock.Mock(status=404), "not found")
    mock_get(mock.ANY).raise_for_status.side_effect = exception

    make_request()
```

However, I'm getting the following error because the exception is raised in the test—causing the test to fail.

```
$ pytest
...
E               requests.exceptions.HTTPError: [Errno <Mock id='4352275232'>] not found

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py:1011: HTTPError
==================================================== 1 failed in 0.52s ====================================================
```

How do I assert on the behavior that occurs when an HTTP exception is raised (e.g. 404 status code)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `pytest.raises` context manager to capture the exception and assert on the error message. For example:

```py
with pytest.raises(HTTPError) as error_info:
    make_request()
    assert error_info == exception
```

**Full example:**

`test_main.py`

```py
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import patch

import pytest
from requests import HTTPError

from main import make_request


@patch("main.get")
def test_main_exception(mock_get):
    exception = HTTPError(mock.Mock(status=404), "not found")
    mock_get(mock.ANY).raise_for_status.side_effect = exception

    with pytest.raises(HTTPError) as error_info:
        make_request()
        assert error_info == exception
```

See [pytest - Assertions about expected exceptions](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions) for more info.